# Can't retrieve access token for oauth

Tags: python, oauth, jira

I'm trying to implement OAuth for an application that retrieves data from our JIRA server via the REST API. I am able to construct and use an authorization url, and get a message indicating that I have successfully authorized my application when I use it. However, when I then try to request the access-token, I always get response code 401, with content 'oauth_problem=token_rejected'.

I am using Python 3, and have pulled apart the code in the 'oauthdance' function within jirashell to see where the breakdown is happening. I'm not using a callback uri, so I specified 'oob' as the callback and can see the verification string in my browser after I authorize the application.

```py
oauth = OAuth1(consumer_key,
signature_method=SIGNATURE_RSA, rsa_key=key_cert_data, resource_owner_key=request_token, resource_owner_secret=request_token_secret, verifier=<string copied from browser>
)
r = requests.post(
server + '/plugins/servlet/oauth/access-token', verify=verify, auth=oauth)
```

I would expect this code to retrieve the access token, but instead it's returning the 401 response. The request_token and request_token_secret appear to be valid and were retrieved via the request-token servlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here: https://community.developer.atlassian.com/t/java-oauth-example-does-not-work/3779/2

The consumer key used with OAuth is case-sensitive. I changed it to exactly match the value entered by our admin in JIRA and got an access token.